# C# 透過したフォームを最背面にしたいのだが…

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

C#でデスクトップアクセサリを作ろうとして躓きました。
フォームのTransparencyKeyをフォームのBackColorに設定して、
BorderStyleをNoneにし、マスコットキャラ的なところまでを
作るには完成しました。

その後、常に最背面に表示させたくて、ネットのサンプルを見て、
下記のように追加しました。

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

    // FindWindow 関数
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr FindWindow(
        string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName
    );


    // SetParent 関数
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr SetParent(
        System.IntPtr hWndChild,
        System.IntPtr hWndNewParent
    );


    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Program Manager のハンドルを取得する
        System.IntPtr hProgramManagerHandle = FindWindow(null, "Program Manager");

        // 正しく取得できた場合は、Program Manager を親ウィンドウに設定する
        if (!hProgramManagerHandle.Equals(System.IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            SetParent(this.Handle, hProgramManagerHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

このコードを実行したところ、最背面に表示するどころか、フォーム自体が完全に
非表示になってしまいます。おまけにタスクバーにも表示されなくなるため、手動で
閉じることもできなくなります。

フォームを透過させてしまうと、最背面に指定することはできなるなるのでしょうか。

もし、実現する方法があれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Aeroが有効になっていますか？ 参考 http://dotlog.info/archives/1702

Comment: 文章が紛らわしかったので一応補足します。Aeroが有効の場合、親にすべきウィンドウは `Program Manager` ではなく、またそれ以外にも問題があった、ということが上の記事に書かれていました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
使っているのはWin8.1ですし、Aeroなんて使ったこともないので有効にはなっていないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 C# Windows Form .NetFramework4.5で以下のコードで透過フォームを最背面に配置できました。

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate bool EnumWindowCallBack(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd1, IntPtr hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);

    // SetParent 関数
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr SetParent(
        System.IntPtr hWndChild,
        System.IntPtr hWndNewParent
    );

    [DllImport("USER32.Dll")]
    static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowCallBack x, IntPtr y);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder s, int nMaxCount);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnumWindows(EnumerateWindow, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    // ウィンドウを列挙するためのコールバックメソッド
    private bool EnumerateWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder sbClassName = new StringBuilder(256);
        int result = GetClassName(hWnd, sbClassName, 256);
        string className = sbClassName.ToString();
        if (className.Equals("WorkerW") || className.Equals("Progman"))
        {
            IntPtr hDt = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
            if (hDt != null && hDt != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetParent(this.Handle, hDt);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

タスクバーに表示はされないようなので、フォーム上の表示されているコントロールの右クリックでコンテキストメニューを表示させて閉じるなどを実装してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 補足です。
上記プログラムはForm上にボタンを1つだけ配置したアプリです。

TransparencyKeyによる透過設定ではアプリが見えなくなる現象が当方でも発生しました。
そこで、OnPaintBackgroundをOverrideし、処理を空とすることで背景の表示をしないようにしてみたところ背景透過のフォームが常に再背面に表示されるようになりました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
しかしうまくいきません。
ソースはそのまま張り付けた(勿論、ボタンのイベントも結び付けてあります)
のですが、やはりすべてが非表示になります。
ボタンを押す前から、既に背景として使用している画像も表示されません。
BorderStyleもSizableのままなのですが、フレームすら消えてしまいます。

何がいけないのでしょうか…？

Comment: プロジェクトを新規に作成してもだめでしょうか。

こちらでも再度新規にプロジェクトを新規に作成し、上記のコードを貼り付けて、usingにSystem.Runtime.InteropServicesを追加、ボタンを追加して実行したところ、ボタンだけが表示され(フレームは表示されません)ることが確認できました。